# Why can't I get output from PHP, using python Popen

Tags: php, python, shell, popen

I have a program that calls PHP from python, with popen, and I don't get any stdout or stderr from my calls.

The problematic lines are:

```
task = subprocess.Popen(
        ['/usr/bin/php', exec_path],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        env=env
    )
stdout_str, stderr_str = task.communicate()
task_result = task.returncode
```

When I replace the PHP path with ls, it works:

```
task = subprocess.Popen(
    ['/bin/ls', exec_path],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    env=env
)

stdout_str, stderr_str = task.communicate()
task_result = task.returncode
# Works as expected
```

And when I run the PHP command from the shell, it does produce output.

For reference, the PHP file is:

```
<?
echo "YAY";
?>%
```

Comment: The `exec_path` is the same in both cases right? I'm wondering if it could be a permission issue.

Comment: But I'm still able to execute the file from command line, as php /tmp/regraphd_testing_dir_A5wdrS/queries/tmp0AKqI6.php,

But yes, the paths are the same

Comment: Shouldn't the PHP file start with `<?php` ?

Comment: Also, what's the `%` at the end for?

Comment: Oh, that's just the shell indicating there's no newline there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. Earlier I had written the file contents, and forgotten to flush() it, so the file was empty when the exec call happened.